# How to ignore certain file e.g. .env when building AWS SAM Lambda Layer?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am using AWS SAM to build lambda layer, which works well.

However, I do double checked that, that layer built includes my local `.env` file, which I do not want to include into the layer content. Any option to exclude/ignore certain files?

I checked (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/building-layers.html) and (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-layerversion.html) Not explain this user case.

```
Resources:
  PrismaClientLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: prisma-client-layer
      ContentUri: orm/
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - nodejs18.x
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: nodejs18.x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure your `.env` file is not in the `orm` folder.

When using `CodeUri` we have the following:

> If a path to a local folder is provided, for the content to be transformed properly the template must go through the workflow that includes `sam build` followed by either `sam deploy` or `sam package`. By default, relative paths are resolved with respect to the AWS SAM template's location.

For Node.js, during the execution of `sam build` the initial steps SAM CLI uses for Layer bundling are:

1. `npm pack -q file:<project-path>/orm`
2. Extract the tgz file into a temporary folder `/tmp/tmp38x93h8u/unpacked`
3. Create the destination folder at `<project-folder>/.aws-sam/build/PrismaClientLayer/nodejs`
4. Copy all unpacked files from item 2 to item 3 folder
5. Inside the `.aws-sam/build/PrismaClientLayer/nodejs` it will run `npm install -q --no-audit --no-save --unsafe-perm --production`
6. Copy `node_modules` dependencies from `.aws-sam/build/PrismaClientLayer/nodejs/node_modules` to `.aws-sam/deps/<build-hash>/node_modules`

[image]

You can debug the process using `aws build --debug`.

**Default behaviour:** Files inside `orm` folder are copied to the destination Layer.

You can have more control over the process by using:

```yaml
Metadata:
  BuildMethod: makefile
```

You will need a `Makefile` inside the `orm` folder to build / copy and do whatever you need to output files into the correct layer destination (which is `.aws-sam/build/PrismaClientLayer/nodejs` in this scenario)

Comment: Thank you for lots of detailed insight. Based on these info, I have included extra `dotenv-cli` to use `.env` file in another location. Now the layer does not include `.env`. Thank you, mate.